# Flutter ListView Text show on multiLine if overflow

Tags: flutter, dart

I have A listView in which I have another listview to show simple text in horizontal but the issue is its overflow on the left side If I give width to listview it's going to scroll list. I want if it's overflow then it will simply go to the next line instead of overflow or scroll.

My code

```
Expanded(
  child: new ListView.builder(
    itemCount: respondedData3['data'].length,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      String TimeFormat = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(DateTime.parse(respondedData3['data'][index]['appointmentDate']));

      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
        child: Container(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            // onTap: widget.onPressed,
            child: Stack(children: [
              Container(
                height: 80,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(TimeFormat, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'SegoeUI-Bold', color: kPrimaryColor)),
                            Text(respondedData3['data'][index]['appointmentTime'].toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, fontFamily: 'SegoeUI', color: textGreyColor))
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          height: 40,
                          width: 1.5,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(respondedData3['data'][index]['serviceProviderName'].toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, fontFamily: 'SegoeUI-Bold', color: textGreyColor)),
                            Container(
                              height: 20.0,
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemCount: serviceShow.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Text('${serviceShow[index]["Name"]} ${serviceShow[index]["Time"]} ${serviceShow[index]["Price"]}'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
)
```

You can see in the image it's showing an overflow error I need to show it in the second line.

[image]

Comment: Try Embedding innner `ListView.builder` with `Expanded` widget

Comment: Try adding `true` to  `softWarp` in text properties

Answer (score 1):

add max lines on your Text

```
  Text(
    'Your multiline text',
    maxLines: 2, //2 or more line you want
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 3,
        //  respondedData3['data'].length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          String TimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
          //  DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(
          //     DateTime.parse(respondedData3['data'][index]['appointmentDate']));

          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
            child: Container(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                // onTap: widget.onPressed,
                child: Stack(children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 80,
                    // width: double.infinity,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  TimeFormat,
                                  // style: TextStyle(
                                  //   fontSize: 14,
                                  //   fontFamily: 'SegoeUI-Bold',
                                  //   color: kPrimaryColor,
                                  // ),
                                ),
                                Text("Time"
                                    // respondedData3['data'][index]
                                    //         ['appointmentTime']
                                    //     .toString(),

                                    // style: TextStyle(
                                    //   fontSize: 13,
                                    //   fontFamily: 'SegoeUI',
                                    //   color: textGreyColor,
                                    // ),
                                    )
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              height: 40,
                              width: 1.5,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "serviceProviderName",

                                    // respondedData3['data'][index]
                                    //         ['serviceProviderName']
                                    //     .toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 13,
                                      // fontFamily: 'SegoeUI-Bold',
                                      // color: textGreyColor
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    height: 20.0,
                                    child: ListView.builder(
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                      itemCount: 33,
                                      itemBuilder:
                                          (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                                              Text(
                                        '{serviceShow[index]["Name"]} {serviceShow[index]["Time"]} {serviceShow[index]["Price"]}',
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: It's scrolling with Expanded I want to show it on another line, not in the scroll.

Comment: change to `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,`

Answer (score 0):

> You get this error because you don't tell specific width For displaying Text widget and your getting text is  huge.Always remeber, in Text widget => use 'overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis' . Because in dynamic application, text can be large

> Use FittedBox to when you want to try your text in limited width. And you want not get overflow error, use **"overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis"**

```
   FittedBox(
        child:
        Container(
          width: 260,
         // height: 50,
          child: const Text(
            "testing1 testing2 testing3 testing4 testing5 testing6 testing7 testing8 testing9 testing10 testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing",
            style: TextStyle(
              // color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              fontSize: 17,
              
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
            maxLines: 4,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis
          ),
        ),
        
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

The text in my app was overflowing too , and  `maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,` was not working since the text was part of the  `Expanded(child: ListView.builder(` so what I did was

> ```
> LimitedBox(
>      maxWidth: 150,
>      child: Text(
>      videoInfo[index]["title"],
>      overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
>      style: TextStyle(
>      fontSize: 18,
>      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>      ),
>      ),
>      )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

use `Expanded` up your `Column` example;

```
Expanded(child: 
   Column(
     children: [
        Text ('long text'),
        Text ('long text 2')
     ]
   )
);
```